# How can i detect new items in rss feed

Tags: iphone, ios

I am making an app that will load stories from rss feed and store them locally in Documents folder, so they would be available offline. My question is: How can i detect new items so i could update the existing stories list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to re-query the feeds. Either add a "Refresh" button which loads new data, or you can have a timer execute a reloading method every few minutes or whatever you require.

Comment: and how would i know which item is new? I don't want it to load the whole channel, i need it top-up the offline storage with new feeds.

Comment: ok, thanks! but is there any other, faster way? it would take a while to compare whole list of results.

Comment: Not that I can think of at the moment.